# CSS dropdown menu adds scroll bars to header div on hover

Tags: html, css

I used the following [example](http://codepen.io/philhoyt/pen/ujHzd) trying to create my own dropdown menu.

I've tried increasing the z-index but my problem is really not that the sub-menu is behind other content. Rather **when I hover over 'Login', scrollbars are added to the header div** and I have to use them to view the sub-menu.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>  
<head>                                                                                                    
<title>Test</title>                                                                               
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">                                           
</head> 
<body>  
<div id="header">
<div id="logo"> 
[ BETA ]
</div>  

<div id="menu_container">                                                                                 
<div id="menu">                                                                                           
    <ul>
    <li><a href=#>Login</a>                                                                           
            <ul>                                                                                      
            <li><a href=#>A</a></li>                                                                  
            <li><a href=#>B</a></li>                                                                  
            <li><a href=#>C</a></li>                                                                  
            </ul>                                                                                     
    </li>
    <li><a href=#>Register</a></li>                                                                   
    <li><a href=#>Events</a></li>                                                                     
    <li><a href=#>About</a></li>                                                                      
    </ul>
</div>  
</div>                                                                                                    
</div>                                                                                                    
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
#header {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    color: #ff8100;
}

#menu_container {
    float: right;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

#menu ul a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li.current-menu-item {
    background: #000000;
}

#menu ul li:hover {
    background: green;
}

#menu ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background:#ffffff;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu ul ul li {
    float: none;
    width:200px;
}

#menu ul ul a {
    line-height: 120%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

#menu ul ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

#menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

**What do I need to do to have the sub-menu appear to be hanging down from the header div and over the rest of the content body?** Thanks and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `overflow: auto` from `.header` and use a clearfix instead:

```
#header {
   background: black;
   color: white;
   padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
   /*overflow: auto;*/ //remove
   position: relative;
   z-index: 999;
}

#header:after{
   content: "";
   display: block;
   clear: both;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/shnuwprr/)

`overflow:auto` is being added to clear the floated items (i prefer `overflow:hidden`) but what it also does is hide the overflow and add scroll bars to view more. Typically that's a good approach except in this case you actually want the subnav to overflow the header.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:

```
#header {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

That oughta' do the trick.
Simple and clean.

Comment: I no longer have the scrollbar problem but now I've arrived at the common dropdown behind other content issue. I added z-index: 999; all over trying to get the menu item on top but with no luck. Where should it go?